# unable to update the ngmodel of select list

Tags: angularjs

**Case** :
I am trying to update the value of ng-model inside the controller but it is not working and i wonder why , any idea ?

**HTML** :

```
  <select ng-model="dumm" ng-options="item.name as item.type for (name, item) in availableFilters" ng-change="selectFilter()"></select>
```

**JS** :

```
$scope.selectFilter = function () {
     $scope.availableFilters[$scope.dumm].visible = true;
     $scope.dumm = "";
};

  $scope.availableFilters = {
    name: {
        type: 'Name',
        name: 'name'
    },
    producttype: {
        type: 'Product type',
        name: 'producttype',
        data: $scope.xxx
    },
    status: {
        type: 'Status',
        name: 'status',
        data: $scope.unitStatusTypes
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$scope.dumm` should be an object rather than a string, otherwise the binding won't work - this fact is quite obscure in Angular's docs. The binding should look like this:

```
<select ng-model="dumm.value"...
```

and the variable's definition:

```
$scope.dumm = {value: ""};
```

Comment: but dumm will be holding the item.name which is a string , why should it be an object ?

Comment: This is just how Angular works :) The bound value cannot be a standalone string/integer, but only an object's property.

Comment: your solution worked in my code but i dont get it so much , can you please check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ghatasheh/khxdtvm6/2/

Comment: @ Vadim Landa any comment on this ? I am trying to figure out how things work :)

Comment: Angular only knows how to bind/watch objects and their properties - I'm not aware of the internal implementation details, so feel free to explore Angular's code yourself :)